# Фильтрация данных с полей формы

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Возник такой вопрос: кто как принимает данные с полей формы?

Допустим, пришла инфа с 10 полей, где разные типы данных (числовые, строковые). Делал примерно так:
`$name = myFilterFunction($_POST['name']);`, и так на все 10 полей.

Дело в том, что данная процедура занимает очень много места в коде, да и минус в том, что, к примеру, поля "Имя пользователя" и "Название статьи" фильтруется одинаково, потому что оба строковые, хотя в названии статьи могут быть такие символы, как !"№;%:? и т.д., а в имени, конечно же, нет. Проверять поля JS - думаю, не вариант, т.к. он может быть отключен или его специально отключили.

Кто как фильтрует данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@xenon](/users/6572/xenon), откройте для себя [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php), [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input-array.php) и т.д. И [@boris_U](/users/30380/boris_u) тоже советую не изобретать велосипеды ;)

Comment: @Deonis: ок. filter_input_array - жуткая вещь :). Очень монстрообразная.

Comment: @boris_U, может, обоснуете фразы "жуткая вещь" и "монстрообразная"? А то я не понимаю. Буковок много?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во первых, $_GET и/или $_POST - это суть массив $_REQUEST. А раз это массив, то можно упростить себе жизнь так:

```
function someInputCheck($var) {
if ($var) return @htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);
}
$_REQUEST = array_map("someInputCheck", $_REQUEST);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo $_REQUEST["c"];
```

Таким способом можно избежать выполнения JS-кода из переменных, ну и попутно выполнить нужные вам проверки.

Answer (score 0):

1. js - обязательно, плевать на тех, кто его выключил. Остальным помогает заполнить форму с первого раза.
2. На сервере все делает фреймворк, иногда описание правил бывает очень громоздким, но оно того стоит. Безопасность превыше всего.